# Isomorphism $f: V/U\stackrel{\sim}{\longrightarrow}V$ with $ U \neq 0_V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible to construct an isomorphism $$f: V/U\stackrel{\sim}{\longrightarrow}V$$ for a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $V$ and a non-trivial subspace $U \subset V$ for finitely dimensional $V$?
How does such an isomorphism look for infinitely dimensional $V$?

Comment: Since V is finite dimensional and U is non-trivial, what can you say about the dimension of the quotient space?

Comment: $dim(V/U)=dim(V)-dim(U)$, thus it is lower and an isomorphism cannot exist? Does one exist for infinitely dimensional $V$?

Comment: @B.Schnebbler Yes, since dimension is an invariant (and, in a sense, the only invariant) under linear isomorphisms.  Consider the countably-infinite direct sum $\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{N}}{V}$, which has countably-infinite dimension.  Then quotient by any single copy of $V$ in this to get another $V$-vector space of countably-infinite dimension, so they are linearly isomorphic.